# Custom nested Layers in keras - how to get output values of each Layer and set name for summary?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have custom layers and want to get the output of one specific layer for the input data. Also, I want to see the names of some or all custom layers in the model summary. But instead it shows only the main layer and not all single sub layers.

Here is an abstracted example.

```
class EncoderLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, dff, rate=0.1):
    super(EncoderLayer, self).__init__()

    self.ffn = point_wise_feed_forward_network(d_model, dff)

    self.layernorm1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
    self.layernorm2 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)

    self.dropout1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)
    self.dropout2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)

  def call(self, x, training, mask):


    attn_output = self.dropout1(x, training=training)
    out1 = self.layernorm1(x + attn_output)  # (batch_size, input_seq_len, d_model)

    ffn_output = self.ffn(out1)  # (batch_size, input_seq_len, d_model)
    ffn_output = self.dropout2(ffn_output, training=training)
    out2 = self.layernorm2(out1 + ffn_output)  # (batch_size, input_seq_len, d_model)

    return out2


class Encoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self,embedding_layer, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, input_vocab_size,
               maximum_position_encoding, rate=0.1):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()

    self.d_model = d_model
    self.num_layers = num_layers

    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_vocab_size, d_model)



    self.enc_layers = [EncoderLayer(d_model, num_heads, dff, rate)
                       for _ in range(num_layers)]

    self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)
    
  def call(self, x, training, mask):

    seq_len = tf.shape(x)[1]

    x = self.embedding(x) 

    x *= tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32))

    x = self.dropout(self.x_fast, training=training)

    for i in range(self.num_layers):
      x = self.enc_layers[i](x, training, mask)

    return x  # (batch_size, input_seq_len, d_model)




def Model(nb_words=50000,MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH=12,d_model=300,act='relu',embedding_matrix=None):


    input_q1 = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
    input_q2 = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')


    Encoder_Layer= Encoder(num_layers=1, d_model=d_model, num_heads=1,
                             dff=64, input_vocab_size=MAX_NB_WORDS,
                             maximum_position_encoding=10000)


    x1 = Encoder_Layer(input_q1, training=False, mask=None)
    x2 = Encoder_Layer(input_q2, training=False, mask=None)


    x = concatenate([x1,x2],1)

    x = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)

    merged = Dropout(0.3)(x)
    merged = BatchNormalization()(merged)

    merged = Dense(64, activation=act)(merged)
    merged = Dropout(0.3)(merged)
    x = BatchNormalization()(merged)

    x = Dense(64,activation=act)(x)

    preds = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)


    model = Model(inputs=[input_q1,input_q2],outputs=preds)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer='adam',
            metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(model.summary())

    return model
```

Now I would like to get the output of the first embedding from the Encoder layer in:

```
x = self.embedding(x)
```

I found the solution via

```
model = build_model() 
# lstm_67 is the second layer.
lstm = K.function([model.layers[0].input], [model.layers[1].output])
lstm_output = lstm([test_x])[0]
```

But model.layers and summary only have:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 12)]         0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 12)]         0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoder (Encoder)               (None, 12, 300)      580264      input_1[0][0]
                                                                 input_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 48, 300)      0           encoder[0][0]
                                                                 encoder[1][0]
                                                                 subtract[0][0]
                                                                 add[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)             (None, 48, 300)      0           concatenate[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNorma (None, 48, 300)      1200        dropout_5[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)                (None, 48, 64)       19264       batch_normalization[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)             (None, 48, 64)       0           dense_16[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 48, 64)       256         dropout_6[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)                (None, 48, 64)       4160        batch_normalization_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)                (None, 48, 1)        65          dense_17[0][0]
==================================================================================================
Total params: 605,209
Trainable params: 604,481
Non-trainable params: 728
_____________________________
```

But since the sublayers and also this embedding layer is not inside the layers and summary I think I have to put them there first.

So it shows only the Encoder Layer. But what if I want each individual EncoderLayer-Layer shown with name? Also, what if I want really all sublayers like self.layernorm1 of each EncoderLayer to be shown in model.layers?

Comment: try to not use custom class layers but simple functions where you combine the layers in the way you want

Comment: I think it is about the build, init and call function I read a few times ago? Do I need a build function in the layer class? Why isnt it shown? What would I need to do that it is shown if I would like to use class of layers?

Comment: Hey, sorry that I instist but how would you do that if you want to use custom layers?

Comment: your it's simply a stacking of existing layers... no need to use custom class... use function

Comment: Could you make an example? Because these are custom layers for the transformer architecture and it would be nice to call a transformer layer. Please give a statement what I need to do because for custom layers you can find a lot of things why this is not shown in the summary.

Comment: I use the code you provided but it's very messy (what are build_model, point_wise_feed_forward_network and much more).. please provide me an update version of it with ALL defined (variable and functions) in order to obtain the summary you reported

Comment: thanks. I will do that! Sorry for this stalking. But I have another issue. Do you know how I save the architecture of a model? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63937724/keras-load-saved-model-systemerror-unknown-opcode